# React Kiosk App keeps crashing on Chrome - Chrome not Responding

Tags: reactjs, windows, google-chrome, crash, kiosk

We have a Kiosk app which runs on Chrome Kiosk mode and is written in React JS. But for some of our Kiosk machines (All of our machines are Windows machines), it seems to be crashing regularly (Approx. %4 of the devices) without any user input or fixed time between crashes.

I reviewed the code several times but never found any background tasks running, or any reason for the Chrome to crash at all.

Because the crashes are irregular, I cannot connect to a problematic device and wait for it to crash for hours to debug the process. And because the app is automatically started via a VB script when Windows is started, the clients often "solve" the crashes by restarting the Kiosk machine, which is time consuming and leads to tons of complaints.

So my questions are;

- Can I somehow force Chrome to restart, or lets say Go to first page in history if it crashes?
- Can I catch errors globally without using ErrorBoundries in JavaScript (It is already implemented and is used for other things)
- I tried using --remote-debugging-port=9222 to use Developer Tools, but I need to be connected to the machine and go to localhost:9222 port manually to use this and cannot afford to be connected to the device all the time. So is there a way to connect and use Developer Tools on 9222 port remotely?
- I tried saving console logs to a file (using Chrome Command Line Arguments) but never saw any "Errors" on the list, so is there any arguments to help me save crash logs to a file to inspect them after the crash?

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: still waiting for any suggestions! cheers!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.